# Changing the value of button when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to change the color of button when clicked. I don't know what is wrong in this code.

```
paginationContainer.find("li").on('click', function() {

    var linkNumber = $(this).text();

    $(linkNumber).removeClass('active').addClass('inactive');
    $(this).removeClass('inactive').addClass('active');

});

.active {
    background: yellow
}

.inactive {
    background: red
}
```

Comment: what does your html look like?

Comment: If there's more than one `li` you'll need to iterate. over them all.

Answer (score 2):

You need to apply the class to the li - not the text, Also you can swapt the classes of active and inactive by using .toggleClasss().

```
paginationContainer.find("li").on('click', function(){
   $(this).toggleClass('active inactive');
});
```

Comment: It will change the background of the li based on the class CSS.

Comment: Never knew about `$(this).toggleClass('active inactive');`, that's just great. +1

Comment: @gavgrif: I don;t want to toggle. I want to change value when i clicked. For instance, if button 1 clicked it should be red and rest should not be changed.

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for something like this

**HTML**

```
<button class="clickMe">
Button1
</button>
<button class="clickMe">
Button2
</button>
<button class="clickMe">
Button3
</button>
<button class="clickMe">
Button4
</button>
```

**CSS**

```
.clickMe{

  padding:3%;
  background-color:cyan;
  color:white;
}
```

**JS**

```
$('.clickMe').click(function(){
$(this).css('background-color',"green");
});
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/397cgxkq/13/)